Why is the Android-wide setup not applicable on BottomSheet or Dialog on Compose?
Settings such as ignoring the system font set by Compose Bottom Sheet or Dialog as a whole, or preventing views from being pushed up when the keyboard is up, do not apply
    private fun nonFontScale(){
        val configuration = resources.configuration
        configuration.fontScale = 1.0f
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    }

Why isn't adjustNothing applied in Components ModalBottomSheet?
It works well with other Compose
Does anyone know why it doesn't work and how to fix it??
Thank you
